# Need help to understand the usage of `liftBase`

Tags: haskell

I am currently reading through (for self studying purpose) the source code of the Bryan O'Sullivan's popular `pool` [library](https://github.com/bos/pool).

And I have a question in the function `takeResource`, which I would like to ask the Haskell experts here.
The function is defined as:

```
takeResource :: Pool a -> IO (a, LocalPool a)
takeResource pool@Pool{..} = do
  local@LocalPool{..} <- getLocalPool pool
  resource <- liftBase . join . atomically $ do
  ents <- readTVar entries
  case ents of
    (Entry{..}:es) -> writeTVar entries es >> return (return entry)
    [] -> do
      used <- readTVar inUse
      when (used == maxResources) retry
      writeTVar inUse $! used + 1
      return $
        create `onException` atomically (modifyTVar_ inUse (subtract 1))
  return (resource, local)
```

The line I am having problem with is

```
...
resource <- liftBase . join . atomically $ do
...
```

Why is here the usage of `liftBase` necessary? Can we also write instead

```
...
resource <- join . atomically $ do
...
```

The compiler accepts both versions. Am I missing here something trivial or why is `liftBase` here necessary?

Thank you in advance for the tips!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I'm responsible for that. No, there's no purpose for it to be there, it can be removed. I think it was necessary before some refactoring. You could send a pull request and be part of an awesome library :)

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the clarification. I'll try to prepare and send a pull request. thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

It is a historical artifact. Initially there was only `withResource` function, and it [used](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool-0.2.0.4/docs/src/Data-Pool.html#withResource) `liftBase` because it lives in `MonadControlIO` class. Then the code was extracted to `takeResource`, but `liftBase` is still there.